# Julia restrict parametric return type

Tags: types, julia, parametric-polymorphism

I want to restrict the parametric return type (a `Vector` of something) of a function.

Say I have a function `f` defined as follows:

```
julia> function f()::Vector{Real}
           return [5]
       end
f (generic function with 1 method)
```

I use `Vector{Real}` because I don't want to restrict myself too much - the return value might change to `[5.0]` at some time.

The problem is, that this causes the `5` to be *cast* to `Real` - Julia essentially forgets the specific type:

```
julia> f()
1-element Vector{Real}:
 5

julia> typeof(f())
Vector{Real} (alias for Array{Real, 1})
```

Note that this is not the case without the parametric type:

```
julia> function g()::Real
           return 5
       end
g (generic function with 1 method)

julia> g()
5

julia> typeof(g())
Int64
```

I would've *hoped* that something like the following would be possible:

```
julia> function f()::Vector{T} where T<:Real
           return [5]
       end
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f()
ERROR: UndefVarError: T not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] f()
   @ Main ./REPL[7]:2
 [2] top-level scope
   @ REPL[8]:1
```

However, this only works for parametric types used on parameters:

```
julia> function f(t::T)::Vector{T} where T<:Real
           return [5]
       end
f (generic function with 2 methods)

julia> f(5)
1-element Vector{Int64}:
 5
```

This is obviously not what I want. Is there a way to achieve this in Julia?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
function f()::Vector{<:Real}
    return [5]
end
```

And now:

```
julia> f()
1-element Vector{Int64}:
 5
```

Comment: This is also equivalent to `function f()::(Vector{T} where T<:Real)`. Without the parentheses, the parser seems to assume the `where` part applies to only the function arguments instead of the return type, hence the `UndefVarError` for `Vector{T}`. Still odd because `where` applies to both for `function f(t::T)::Vector{T} where T<:Real`, `f(5.6)` demonstrates this.

Comment: @Bat Yes! those parenthesis around `where` are needed quite often on different occasions so this is worth to know. BTW you provided very nice answer to another question and then deleted it because it was the same minute as mine - why to delete? Your answer was actually more detailed and hence useful for other people. I believe it does not make to delete the answer only because it is 10 seconds later :)

Comment: I had the opposite opinion, I thought yours was clearer and mine was an distractingly redundant, so I scrapped mine =P.